# -[CollectionCell _setReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`CollectionCell` is a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. For learning purposes, the only difference is a single subview.

No interface builder. All in code.

I can do it like this for iOS 5…

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[CollectionCell class]
    forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];
```

…but it breaks in iOS 6, and I can't find any information.

Comment: How are you able to use that on iOS 5 if `UICollectionView` is iOS 6+ only?

Comment: Would have been helpful to mention I'm using PSTCollectionView, huh. It doesn't actually make any practical difference – in iOS 6, it just uses UICollectionView.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Cause... I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Morkrom I have absolutely no idea what I did.

Comment: hah,.... somehow I did too.

Answer (score 1):

Your subclassed CollectionCell doesn't have the "`registerClass: forCellWithReuseIdentifier`" method.

Your "`UICollectionView`" (which uses and displays CollectionCell objects) does.

Call "`registerClass: forCellWithReuseIdentifier`" on your collection view instead of the cell.

Comment: `- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

Comment: if your code looks like what you put above ("`_collectionView registerClass: ...`"), then your "`_collectionView`" is actually a cell and not the view which it should be.

Comment: Aside from that being impossible, I just logged `_collectionView.class` and got a view class, **not** a cell class.

Comment: And that's still with the "`unrecognized selector sent to instance`" error still happening?  Did you check to make sure your custom class is set correctly on that cell, also that the reuse identifier in the XIB or storyboard for that cell is set to "CollectionCell"?

Comment: No interface builder. All in code. // Yes, I'm still getting the error, and yes, I'm being careful about what class is used where.

Comment: One last attempt to help you get to a solution. According to the [Apple documentation on the "`reuseIdentifier`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionReusableView/reuseIdentifier), "The collection view sets this value when it first creates the view, and the value cannot be changed later." If your collection view is visible, the reuse identifier has already been set. Try setting this "`registerClass`" in your view controller's "`viewDidLoad`" or "`viewWillAppear`".

Comment: Not sure what fixed it, but something changed in the last few minutes seems to have done it. Helpful.

Comment: bummer... I have the same problem, and I can't just wait for something to change in the last few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `UICollectionViewCell` classes extend `PSUICollectionViewCell`. I had the same issue happen to me and found out that my cells were extending `PSTCollectionViewCell`.